# How to add refferer url in script's src link

Tags: javascript, php, html

Our client have below link added in their site (given by us) which call our test.php file to use it as library and we return some script as well as we store some data.

Script tag is as per below on client's side,

```
<script src='https://example.com/test.php?id=194&referer='WHAT SHOULD I Write Here'></script>
```

test.php is as per below on our server,

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$clientsrefferer = $_GET['referer'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//below referer becomes address of client's webpage visited by their customer
$visitedwebpage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=XXXXXX;dbname=XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", 'XXXXX');
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $query = "insert into table (ID,IP,Referer,Page) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute(array($id, $ip, $clientsrefferer, $visitedwebpage));

    echo "document.write('Returning some script')";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}

?>
```

We want to check if client's website is searched and visited using any search engine referer. To get it from javascript,

```
document.referrer
```

can be use.

But I want to attach document.refferer value to the  tag only which we gave it to our client. Is it possible?
Is there any other way to do that?

If question is not clear, let me know so I can try to do more clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the referrer detail and dynamically add the script tag on client side. Like below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var my_script = document.createElement('script');
  my_script.setAttribute('src','https://example.com/test.php?id=194&referer=' + document.referrer);
  document.head.appendChild(my_script);
</script>
```